# HTML5 download attribute not working with 301 Moved Permanently

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make auto download file from URL with 301 Moved Permanently like this:

```
<a href="myserverapi/download?fileId=123" download="image.jpg" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

But it does not auto download the image.

Instead it only displays the image on the new tab instead of providing the file as a download.

Please suggest any other way of doing this

Comment: You mean you want the new tab to perform the redirect, and then download the file, but instead it's only displaying the image?

Comment: No. I want to auto download file from Url

Comment: does your url end-point have `Content-Type: image/jpg` and `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="image.jpg"` header?

Comment: The endpoint just redirect (301) to a url of image (someurl.com/image.jpg)

Comment: And you want it to *download* the image instead of *displaying* the image? That's the desired functionality?

Comment: Exactly. It is what I want to do

Comment: Sorry, I'd misunderstood. Thanks for the clarification. 



It's up to you, but in your question, you might say "But it does not auto download the image. Instead it only displays the image on the new tab instead of providing the file as a download. Please suggest any other way of doing this."

Comment: Okay. Thank you. Do you have any suggest?

Comment: I have one idea; please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `download` attribute in the  tag, you might consider just changing the response headers instead.

In the response from the server, if you set the `Content-Disposition` header to `attachment`, like **@BadPiggie** said, then the image file will download instead of display.

If you choose to use this header like this, then the `download` attribute is not needed I believe.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Comment: Thank for your answer. But, what if my server just Redirect to other URL image? (Not from my Server)

Comment: Hm... that's a little more difficult. Let me think about it...

Comment: @mikenlanggio Yo, I haven't had time to look at this, but is there any way you can simply provide the external URL in the <a>, instead of providing an internal URL that redirects to an external URL? I.E. can you skip the redirect altogether?

Answer (score 1):

As you said in comment,

> The endpoint just redirects (301) to a URL of image
> (someurl.com/image.jpg)

The issue is in your endpoint `myserverapi/download?fileId=123`. Because the endpoint **redirects** you instead of serving the requested file. This means that the URL doesn't allow you to access the file for some reason.

Maybe, You are using a **Temporary URL**, So it's throwing `301 error` after expiration. So there is nothing wrong with your HTML code!

Answer (score 0):

So.. the problem is that the link opens in a new tab and that is NOT the desired behavior?

If that is the case change:

```
target="_blank"
```

for

```
target="_self"
```

Target blank forces the link to be opened in a new tab, check this: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Comment: It will download image instead of display image?

Comment: @Jhollman this will display the image in the current tab; the goal is to provide a download of the image file in a new tab. Simple misunderstanding of the issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

u can use some server side script if you have the full path to the image, redirect to this page and download it from there

```
$filename = "https://developers.google.com/homepage-assets/images/chromeos-logo.png";
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename. '"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
    readfile($filename);
```

this will trigger downloading of the image not opening it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the question is dealing with a same-origin link, a possible cause for this behaviour is older Firefox versions which hadn't implemented propagating the filename across redirects — the feature seems to have been added somewhere between v78 and v91, which could very well have been after this question was asked.

In v91 this block is present in the `HttpBaseChannel::SetupReplacementChannel` function:

```cpp
  if (sameOriginWithOriginalUri) {
    newChannel->SetContentDisposition(mContentDispositionHint);
    if (mContentDispositionFilename) {
      newChannel->SetContentDispositionFilename(*mContentDispositionFilename);
    }
  }
```

( at https://searchfox.org/mozilla-esr91/source/netwerk/protocol/http/HttpBaseChannel.cpp#4414 )

Note that `mContentDispositionFilename` is assigned with the `download='...'` attribute value at an earlier stage.

In v78 however this code is absent — see https://searchfox.org/mozilla-esr78/source/netwerk/protocol/http/HttpBaseChannel.cpp#4098